# why Avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindow closes?

Tags: c#

After this line:

```
deviceHandle = Avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindow("", Constants.WS_VISIBLE | Constants.WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 10, 10, handle, deviceId);
```

my application stops.
The initialization is:

```
private IntPtr deviceHandle;
```

It´s a console application. My objective is to create an .exe file that records with webcam without user interface or any capture window, just the webcam recording.

Comment: There is not enough information (debugging or otherwise) here. if your app is crashing you need to try and catch the error, if you cant, you need to look at the event logs. However saying your app closes could be because one of many issues. If you want help on this, you really do need to start debugging this and creating a fuller picture in the question with your debugging results

Comment: Show the definition you have for `Avicap32.capCreateCaptureWindow`, better yet, show all your code.

Comment: AVicap32 is a public class with it´s respective attributes

Comment: [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
        public extern static IntPtr capCreateCaptureWindow(
            string title,
            uint style,
            int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height,
            IntPtr window,
            int id
        );

Comment: i tried with a try catch block, but never reaches the catch!, it just close the app, as i told you